# Считывание информации с изображения

Tags: вывод, java, ввод

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать такую вещь (или где почитать про это): я выбираю несколько позиций на экране, где будут появляться цифры. Затем я должен считать эти цифры с экрана и записать  их  в текстовый файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от вашего графического фреймворка.

Например, если это Swing, вам подойдёт [`JTextField`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_jtextfield.htm) или [другие контейнеры текста](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).

Если вы не пользуетесь никаким графическим фреймворком, вам придётся выбрать какой-нибудь.

---

Если же вы хотите считать ввод *другой* программы, вам придётся воспользоваться системно-зависимыми средствами. Например, в Windows обычно вам нужно найти *окно*, принадлежащее полю ввода текста, и опросить его содержимое. (Но так не пойдёт для программ на WPF, там вам придётся воспользоваться accessiblity-интерфейсами.) Но здесь, повторюсь, ваша задача становится платформо-специфической.

Comment: @VladD, скорее всего автор вопроса имел в виду распознавание изображеия в набор символов, а не получить их напрямую с какой-то программы.

Comment: @SuperCreeper: Вы правы, но текст контрола чаще всего можно получить и так, без того, чтобы считывать его с картинки.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно именно то, что сказал @SuperCreeper:распознавание изображения в набор символов. Не могли бы вы мне что-то посоветовать в данном вопросе? Я поверхностно  погуглил - в основном все пишут про нейросети, но мне кажется, что есть какое-то более простое решение.

Comment: @111xbot111: Вы точно уверены, что у вас нет контрола?

Если вам кровь из носу нужна именно картинка, я бы не советовал писать свой велосипед, а воспользоваться готовой [OCR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)-системой, их много.

Comment: @VladD, да, OCR то, что нужно, спасибо. А не могли бы вы мне подсказать, какую именно выбрать? И есть ли годные русскоязычные туториалы на какие-то из них?

Comment: @111xbot111: К сожалению, совсем не имел дела с OCR, так что мне трудно что-либо посоветовать. Думаю, о выборе OCR стоит задать отдельный вопрос. Продумайте, что вас интересует: ценовая политика (или только freeware), качество распознавания, скорость, возможность обучения нестандартным шрифтам, API для интересующего вас языка?

OCR обычно работает с картинками, так что снять картинку вам понадобится самостоятельно.